# How to find a specific column from a list of arrays

Tags: python

I have a list of multidimensional arrays and need to calculate the mean for each dimension. I want to extract column[1] data as a list and send it as a parameter to a method in python. Here is my data:

```
[array([2.33700000e+06, 4.16779479e-01, 9.31000000e-04, 1.99000000e-13,0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]), array([2.33700000e+06,4.16779479e-01, 9.31000000e-04, 1.99000000e-13,0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00])]
```

and I want to do some operations for column[1] data like doing an operation on `[4.16779479e-01,4.16779479e-01]`. How can I do it in python?

Comment: It would be easier for us to illustrate you solution if you provide more details, i.e. How to run your code, what operations you want to do, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You question looks like you are just trying to process the columns of a matrix.  If it is an N by M matrix and you have your matrix stored in a variable called my_mat you could do something like

```
for i in range(len(my_mat[0])):
    col = [arr[i] for arr in my_mat]
    # process your column.
```